# Exercise 13 the hard way python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, argv, sys

I'm working on Exercise 13 from Python the hard way. I'm trying to learn python 3 so I'm trying to convert the code from what I've learned at codecademy. I thought that I made a typing error so I copied his code in to my IDE. I'm getting an error. Can you guys please explain why this is happening for me. I've done a hand full of searches and couldn't find any one getting this error. Thank you guys for helping. It's exactly the same except for the () it needs to run.

script, first, second, third = argv

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

```
 from sys import argv

 script, first, second, third = argv

 print ("The script is called:", (script))
 print ("Your first variable is:", (first))
 print ("Your second variable is:", (second))
 print ("Your third variable is:", (third))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that you are not passing enough arguments to the script. 
This means, the var `argv` has only the name of the script and no more. Check it with `len(argv)`

You should call this in the way:

```
python myscript.py variable1 variable2 variable3
```

If you are calling your script from the IDE, you have to configure it to pass the extra arguments.

You can also print dynamically the variables passed to the script:

```
print('Script is called: %s' % argv[0])

for var_number, var in enumerate(argv[1:]):
    print('The var number %s is: %s' % (var_number, var))
```

By the way, the brackets around the variable names are unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just passing this in command line:-

```
root@root:-# python foo.py
```

You should pass:-

```
root@root:~# python foo.py first second third
```

Ouput:-

```
The script is called: foo.py
Your first variable is: first
Your second variable is: second
Your third variable is: third
```

Comment: That's a python2 output.